# How to add another css file inside of css file?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, minify

I am making web application. and I try to optimization in my web page.
So i am working minify css, js files.

I want to **another css file in a css file**.
As below picture, How to make file in CLI?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`@import url("otherCSSFile.css");`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/@import

Comment: Well.. I'll make new min.css file use to 'clean-css'. So i want to make new files below all self css file

Comment: @JangSeonHo You might be able to drag and drop your files into each other to change their visual position in the hierarchy. Otherwise, I suspect it's a property of having the `.min.css` extension, which means that extra space characters have been removed from the file.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by importing the css file. 
The first rule in the style sheet is the @import rule.

```
@import "mystyle.css";
@import url("mystyle.css");
```

Some Old browsers may not support this one.

you can refer this link fore example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-include-one-css-file-in-another/